# ConfigParser - get entire section as dict and set values

Tags: python, with-statement, configparser

What I'd like to do (ideally) is use `with` with a dictionary to set an entire section of parameters at once. After some experimenting I came up with the following code, which raises `AttributeError`:

```
import configparser
import os

CONFIG_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) + '/config.ini'
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
assert open(CONFIG_PATH)
config.read(CONFIG_PATH)

with dict(config.items('Settings')) as c:
    c['username'] = input('Enter username: ')
```

config.ini file:

```
[Settings]
username = ''
```

The traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    with dict(config.items('Settings')) as c:
AttributeError: __enter__
```

I feel like I'm using `configparser` wrong here, but I'd like to write some beautiful code to set `config.ini` parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a dictionary with `with` because a dict is not a context manager.

```
with dict() as d:
    print d
```

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 6, in <module>
    with dict() as d:
AttributeError: __exit__
```

https://paiza.io/projects/aPGRmOEmydbJL2ZeRtF-3A?language=python

An object must define `__enter__` and `__exit__` in order to be used as a context manager.

documentation: http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html